# how to successfully switch between adapters while still being able to make toolbar disappear

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

I received help a while ago by a hero that helped me make a `Toolbar` disappear when an `ImageView` was clicked by using a callback function and an interface. I have copied this kind of algorithm for a different page view adapter and it works completely fine in the starting page adapter, but when I switch it, the toolbar doesn't disappear and reappear even though the tapping works. I have tried this for a while, but no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

**from adapter1.kt**

```
 private lateinit var pageImageCallback: PageImageCallback

    fun setPageImageCallback(pageImageCallback: PageImageCallback) {
        this.pageImageCallback = pageImageCallback
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        val image_layout: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_item, container, false)
        val page_image: PhotoView = image_layout.findViewById<View>(R.id.page_image) as PhotoView

        Glide.with(image_layout).load(PageList[position].link).placeholder(R.drawable.drip_splash_theme).error(R.drawable.drip_splash_theme).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).priority(Priority.HIGH).into(page_image)


        page_image.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            pageImageCallback.onClick()
        })

        container.addView(image_layout)
        return image_layout
    }
```

**from adapter2**

```
    private lateinit var pageImageCallback: PageImageCallback

    fun setPageImageCallback(pageImageCallback: PageImageCallback) {
        this.pageImageCallback = pageImageCallback
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val newView: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.vertical_pager_item, null)
        val web_image: PhotoView = newView.findViewById<View>(R.id.chapterPage) as PhotoView

        Glide.with(context).load(Data[position].link).dontTransform().into(holder.chapter_title)


        holder.chapter_title.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            pageImageCallback.onClick()
        })


    }
```

**from interface**

```
package com.example.dripk.Interface

interface PageImageCallback {
    fun onClick()
}
```

now for my activity file, it is pretty big but the point of it is that I have four different versions that i display the images. One is horizontal where it displays images in a regular gallery, which has two sub category where you can change the direction of reading from left to right or from right to left and the final way the `ImageView` is displayed in vertical and that is throw a reyclerview. But when I switch the views using the my menu settings, it just doesn't respond after the first switch. I have tried implementing a different interface for vertical reading but I had no luck. I feel its due to my lack of understanding of interface and callbacks. But again, I appreciated any help.

**from page_activity.kt**

```
class Page_Activity : AppCompatActivity(),
    PageImageCallback, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    private var myViewPager: HorizontalAdapter? = null
    private var Vertical: VerticalViewAdapter? = null
    private var reading_direction: Float? = 180F


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewer)
    


        HorizontalView()

    }
private fun HorizontalView() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_Horizontal)


        val myrv = findViewById<View>(R.id.right_page) as ViewPager
        myViewPager = HorizontalAdapter(this, lstPages)
        myrv.rotationY = reading_direction!!
        myViewPager!!.setPageImageCallback(this)

        myrv.setPageTransformer(false,
            ViewPager.PageTransformer { page, position ->
                page.rotationY =
                    reading_direction as Float
            })
        myrv.adapter = myViewPager

       



    }

    private fun VerticalView() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_Vertical)
        val myrv = findViewById<View>(R.id.recycler) as RecyclerView
        Vertical = VerticalViewAdapter(this, lstPages)
        Vertical !!.setPageImageCallback(this)
        myrv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
            this,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
            false
        )
        myrv.adapter = Vertical

    }
```

**solution**

```
       override fun onClick() {
        val presenterHorizontal11 = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.presenterHorizontal)
        val presenter11Horizontal = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.presenter1Horizontal)
        val presenterVertical22 = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.presenterVertical)
        val presenter11Vertical = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.presenter1Vertical)

        if (view == 1) {
            if (presenterVertical22.visibility == View.INVISIBLE) {
                presenterVertical22.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                presenter11Vertical.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                presenterVertical22.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                presenter11Vertical.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }

        if (view == 2) {
            if (presenterHorizontal11.visibility == View.INVISIBLE) {
                println("webtoon visible")
                presenterHorizontal11.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                presenter11Horizontal.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                presenterHorizontal11.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                presenter11Horizontal.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }

    }
    override fun onMenuItemClick(p0: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        return when (p0?.itemId) {
            R.id.item1 -> {
                view = 1
                MangaView()
                true
            }
            R.id.item2 -> {
                view = 2
                WebToonView()
                true
            }
            R.id.item3 -> {
                true
            }
            R.id.left -> {
                view = 1
                reading_direction = 0F
                MangaView()
                true
            }
            R.id.right -> {
                view = 1
                reading_direction = 180F
                MangaView()
                true
            }

            else -> false
        }
    }
```

**from vertical_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity.Page_Activity"
    android:id="@+id/web_viewer"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/reader">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/presenter"
            layout="@layout/presenter">
        </include>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/presenter1"
            layout="@layout/presenter1">
        </include>

    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**from horizontal_reader**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activity.Page_Activity"
    android:id="@+id/viewer"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/reader">



        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:layoutDirection="locale"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/right_page">
        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>



        <include
            android:id="@+id/presenter"
            layout="@layout/presenter">
        </include>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/presenter1"
            layout="@layout/presenter1">
        </include>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**from presenter1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#2C2C2C">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/to_chapters"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#2C2C2C"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24_2"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|top">
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="275dp"
                android:background="#2C2C2C"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:onClick="showPopup">

            </Button>


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/name"

                android:text="Chapter Name"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>
</Toolbar>
```

**from presenter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#2C2C2C">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="278dp"
        android:background="#2C2C2C"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24"
        android:focusable="true">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2C2C2C"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_forward_24"
        android:focusable="true">

    </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</Toolbar>
```

Comment: Hi Maj, I'm trying to make sure, the behaviour you are getting after pressing the switch is your `Toolbar` become `invisible` and can't go `visible`? Also, could you explain a bit about what is the difference between `presenter` and `presenter1`?

Comment: Yeah, so it works perfectly fine with the visible to invisible but when I switch using a menu setting that I have it gets stuck on visible maybe because thats what it ended up last, with the whole switching in settings and all. So presenter1 and persenter is basically what I have for two different Toolbars where the linear layout for one is the top of the screen display and the second is the bottom.

Comment: i prolly can fit both on the same xml, but I never thought it mattered

Comment: Hmm, okay, could you please show your `activity_Horizontal` and `activity_Vertical` layout code?

Comment: Got it, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problems lies in your `onClick()` function

```
    override fun onClick() {
        if (presenter.visibility == View.INVISIBLE) {
            println("clicked")
            presenter.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            presenter1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            presenter.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            presenter1.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
    }
```

Here you are using Kotlin Android Extension, to access the ID of the layout for `presenter` and `presenter1`.

You also define exactly the same ID for `presenter` and `presenter1` in `activity_Horizontal` and `activity_Vertical`

So, in your `page_activity` there must be an import like this

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_Horizontal.presenter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_Horizontal.presenter1
```

This is why, when you switch to `VerticalView()`, then do a tapping, there is no reaction because it is referencing to your `presenter` and `presenter1` in `activity_Horizontal`.

You can solve this by making a difference for the layout ID like `presenterHorizontal`, `presenter1Horizontal`, `presenterVertical`, and `presenter1Vertical`.

Then in your `onClick()` function, add another checker like this

```
override fun onClick() {
    if (viewer.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
       if (presenterHorizontal.visibility == View.INVISIBLE) {
           println("clicked")
           presenterHorizontal.visibility = View.VISIBLE
           presenter1Horizontal.visibility = View.VISIBLE
       } else {
           presenterHorizontal.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
           presenter1Horizontal.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
       }
    } else {
       if (presenterVertical.visibility == View.INVISIBLE) {
           println("clicked")
           presenterVertical.visibility = View.VISIBLE
           presenter1Vertical.visibility = View.VISIBLE
       } else {
           presenterVertical.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
           presenter1Vertical.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: First and foremost, thank you for putting time into the solution. Thank to you I have understand the problem that lies within my code. I have edited your solution, using the knowledge you just taught me, to basically change the first if statement to an int value to check whether I am changing the vertical presenter or the horizontal presenter. Which works! but i do have a problem changing directions which I think I can fix very soon.

Comment: So get this, it is able to react accordingly for about two rotations until it stops being responsive

Comment: Okay, no problem. So you solved your initial problem then got a new problem?

Comment: More like, its the same problem but now a different viewer is included

Comment: its so weird, I have print statements showing me thats it been clicked but the xml is just not responding.

Comment: try adding `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after changing your adapter

Comment: have you tried to debug it? did it enters the correct `if` section?

Comment: Yup, enters correctly, literally after the first rotation to vertical and back it does not work

Comment: Do you think putting the whole file will be usefull?

Comment: No, there's no need to post whole file. This is quite strange. Try changing from Kotlin Android Extensions to `findViewById` for accessing the `presenterHorizontal` and friends.

Comment: Yes for some reason that works, I will show you what i added thanks to you

Comment: glad to hear that, no problem :)